# What is the device called when you use the same word but with two different meanings in a phrase for effect

Tags: british-english

What is the name of the device used when an author uses the same word to different effects in a sentence. Here, the word 'good' is used as both a noun and adjective 
e.g. 'and good goods swimming in the water' - Samuel Pepys

Answer (score 3):

This is a kind of [**antanaclasis**.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclasis)

As defined by the *OED*, antanaclasis is

> A figure of speech involving repetition of a word in a different sense.

A famous example is ["Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)

However, antanaclasis is not limited to using the same word multiple times as different parts of speech.  So while "good goods" involves "good" used as both a noun and adjective, it qualifies as antanaclasis, but phrases also qualify when they use different *senses* of a word in the same part of speech.

For example, from Shakespeare's *Henry V*:

> "To England will I **steal**, and there I'll **steal**"

This phrase uses two different *senses* of the word "steal," but in both cases they are verbs.

Comment: +1 for steal.... steal and good goods, but what do the 8 buffaloes mean?

Comment: @ab2 the link is to the Wikipedia page, which gives a thorough description, better than I could do in an answer or comment.